# Immutable push/add (redux/immutable.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, redux

I have an immutable object as my state in a redux reducer, and am trying to add/updates objects to a list.

**Here's my reducer:**

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable'

const initialState = fromJS({
  editable: true
})

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {

    case 'CONTENT_MODE': {
      return state.set('editable', action.editable ? false : true) 
    }

    case 'UPDATE_CONTENT': {
      return state.set(action.page, action.content)
      // action.page = String
      // action.content = {}
    }

    default: {
      return state
    }

  }
}
```

I want to add objects to the page key, however if it currently exists update the values. I've tried updateIn and add() the callback, but I'm fairly new to immutable.js and am not sure how to approach it correctly.

The set() method rewrites the 'page' value entirely, whilst I need to push the value and only set if it exists, ending up with:

**Example**

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  editable: true,
  home: {
    title: {
      name: 'this is the name',
      value: 'this is the value'
    },
    body: {
      name: 'this is the name',
      value: 'this is the value'
    }
  },
  page1: {
    title: {
      name: 'this is the name',
      value: 'this is the value'
    },
    body: {
      name: 'this is the name',
      value: 'this is the value'
    }
  }  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the full path of where you want to add something from your action, you could use SetIn with a keypath. Example, say you want to add a footer to page1:

```
const footer = {name: 'Footer', value: "I'm a footer!" }
return state.setIn(["page1", "footer"], fromJS(footer)
```

If you need to update things (ie say footer has name and value but then you're updating it to also have a style property) you could use mergeIn which is more like Object.assign:

```
const myNewData = {footer: {style: "myStyle"}}
console.log(state.mergeIn(["page1"], fromJS(myNewData);

  --> { page1: { name: 'Footer'
               , value: "I'm a footer!"
               , style: 'myStyle'
               }
      }
```

If you merged in another object, it would add to the props of page1. If that object had a property with the same name, the value would be overwritten.